# Проблемы с xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, xmlhttprequest

Пытаюсь риализовать следущее: на сайте есть некое меню, работающее по `onclick="followLink(event, this)"` функции. Все, в принципе отрабатывает нормально, но на одной из страниц - у меня просто не подгружается яваскрипт, который должен работать с неким плеером (он тоже использует яваскрипт. Т.е. при заходе на страницу я вижу в линках нужный яваскрипт в исходном коде, но плеер его отрабатывает, будто его нет вовсе.

Сам метод плавной смены страниц:

```js
function followLink(event, link)
   {
    
    var nameLink = link.innerHTML;
    uploadContent(link.href+'&ajax=1');
    history.pushState({title:nameLink, href:link.href}, null, link.href);
    updateTitle(nameLink);
    event.preventDefault();
   }

   function updateTitle(title)
   {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    link.setAttribute('type','text/css');
    link.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('href','/templates/styles/player.css');
    link.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    link.setAttribute('rel','javascript');
    link.setAttribute('href','/templates/js/jquery.jplayer.js');
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    elm.DOM = title;
   }

   function uploadContent(link)
   {
      var cont = document.getElementById('content');
      cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
     function createRequestObject() {
     processData:false
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined') {
     XMLHttpRequest = function() {
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
      catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
      catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
      catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
      catch(e) {}
       throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
     };
      }
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
 
      var http = createRequestObject();
      if( http ) {
      http.open('get', link);
      http.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if(http.readyState == 4) {
         $("#content").css("display", "none");
       $("#content").fadeOut(1000);

       $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
     
      cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;
      }
      }
      http.send(null);  
      } else {
      document.location = link;
      }
   }

   window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    uploadContent(e.state.href);          
    updateTitle(e.state.title);
   }, false );
```

Comment: В коде самаго плеера не встречается нигде e.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: Нет..... Я отказался от вышеописанной функции с xmlhttprequest в связи с тем, что у пользователей началась дикая нагрузка на процессоры. Сейчас разбираюсь с JQury, где код и прожорливость в разы меньше. Однако этот вариант нещадно вырезает все, что в тегах <script>

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateTitle(title)
{
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    link.setAttribute('type','text/css');
    link.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('href','/templates/styles/player.css');
    link.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    link.setAttribute('rel','javascript');
    link.setAttribute('href','/templates/js/jquery.jplayer.js');
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    elm.DOM = title;
}
```

Это то зачем не пойму это лишнее. Нужно делать верх и низ не менялся чтоб ну еще менюшка , а меняеться тока середина и все ява будут загружены один раз в шапку например и нагрузка в разы смениться .